# How can I make two functions a single function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have these two functions:

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTextarea").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}

function myFunction1() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTextarea1").value;
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = x;
}
```

and I do not succeed to merge them into a single function.

Comment: `function myFnction3() {myFunction();MyFunction1();}`

Comment: And what is your problem when you try to merge those two functions?

Comment: If you combine them just do not redeclare x (only one var x)

Comment: Or you can do `function setHtml(num=''){document.getElementById("demo"+num).innerHTML = document.getElementById("myTextarea"+num).value`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
function myFunction(inputId,targetId) {
        var x = document.getElementById(inputId).value;
        document.getElementById(targetId).innerHTML = x;
}
myFunction('myTextarea','demo');
myFunction('myTextarea1','demo1');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have this error:  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null at myFunction`

Comment: can you check your textarea id.  full example <textarea id="myTextarea">
demo
</textarea>

<textarea id="myTextarea1">
demo1</textarea>

<div id="demo1"></div>
<div id="demo"></div>

<script>
function myFunction(inputId,targetId) {
        var x = document.getElementById(inputId).value;
        document.getElementById(targetId).innerHTML = x;
}
myFunction('myTextarea','demo');
myFunction('myTextarea1','demo1');

</script>

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like:

```
function myFunction() {
    var textArea = document.getElementById("myTextarea").value;
    var textArea1 = document.getElementById("myTextarea1").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = textArea;
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = textArea1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

insertValue('Value','Inner') this is a function which get 2 arguments, first - value id, and second inner id. You can put any ID and use this multipurpose function

```js
    function insertValue(id_value, id_inner) {
      let x = document.getElementById(id_value).value;
      document.getElementById(id_inner).innerHTML = x;
    }

    insertValue('Value','Inner');
```

```html
<input  id="Value" type="" name="" value="value which you want to put">
 <div id="Inner">inner text which you will dont see</div>
```